# Docker sync on mac

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-machine

I am new to docker but I really love the concept of containerising my app. I have already setup all the containers and am now trying to increase the speed as it is extremely slow on mac (like 15 seconds or more for every request the app makes).

Docker sync promises to solve this problem but I am really struggling to get my head around it. Can anyone please help me out? How can I use docker sync on a Mac to improve the speed of my local development environment? I have gone through the documentation and set up the docker-sync and docker-compose-dev to the best of my abilities, but I am not managing to make it work. Could somebody please help me understand what docker sync is actually doing and therefore how to set it up?

Comment: This is a matter of filesystem support. Read https://dev.to/kovah/cut-your-docker-for-mac-response-times-in-half-with-docker-sync-1e8j

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've been scouting the internet but hadn't seen that. Hope it solves my problem.

Comment: In the end I managed to speed things up by 70-80% by adding :delegated at the end of each volume in the docker-compose.yml file.

Comment: I was not aware of this option! Very interesting...